# Unable to start a nodejs app on ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, ubuntu-20.04

I just moved to ubuntu recently and I tried running a node app with the usual way git clone > npm i but I am having this error back when I try to run it.

**It is a create-react-app app**

Also it was running smoothly in wsl2

error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/Main/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/pages/Main/main.scss)
Error: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/bihire/development/react/ikaze_web_app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-84/binding.node)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ikaze_web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.54",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.6",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "material-ui-chip-input": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "modernizr": "^3.11.2",
    "node-sass": "^*",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-measure": "^2.3.0",
    "react-parallax": "^3.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.6.12",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-state-sync": "^3.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/icons-mdi": "^1.0.105",
    "@iconify/react": "^1.1.3"
  }
}
```

from my eyes it seems to be problem with node-sass but I am not sure

Is there  some thing I should do to fix that?

Comment: Delete your package.lock.json, node_modules and then again run these two commands npm install and then npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: I that with no sucess, however I am getting this  warning while app building `(node:64779) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use "node --trace-deprecation ..." to show where the warning was created)` @Anku

Comment: Looks like it's similar to this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found see if updating it helps.

Comment: already did that with no sucess @Anku

Comment: update your ```package.json```  ```"node-sass": "^4.14.1"``` remove these ```node_modules, yarn.lock, package-lock.json``` and install dependencies again

Comment: I got the same output again @d337

Comment: Check your node version, could be an incompatibility

Comment: Thx fam, It was the node version that weren't the same @YoandryCollazo

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur with native (i.e. compiled, non-Javascript) npm modules when you install Node using the Ubuntu software manager.

For example, Ubuntu 20.04 comes with a system version of `glibc 2.31`.

However when you install the current latest version of Node via the Ubuntu software manager, it comes as a Snap package which also installs dependency package `core` containing `glibc 2.23`, and it is this one that your system version of Node will use (hence the path beginning `/snap/core/current/lib/` in the error message, instead of just `/lib/`). Unfortunately, when you install native modules and the bindings are either downloaded or compiled locally for your system, the versions of the dependencies that the Snap package version of Node will be using are not taken into account, hence the error.

You should find that if you download the *same version* of Node from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org) and run that binary instead of the system version from the Snap package then you won't get the error.

The solution is therefore not to install Node from the Ubuntu software manager. Use `nvm` or manual install instead.